# Google Play applications stats CSV changed?

Tags: google-api, google-play-services, google-cloud-storage, google-php-sdk

I made a **PHP** script last month to retrieve my application's statistiques. Everything works well but since the **1st December**, the **CSV** output downloaded has changed. Indeed, before the 1st Dec I had the followings columns :

```
Date,Package Name,Current Device Installs,Daily Device Installs,Daily Device Uninstalls,Daily Device Upgrades,Current User Installs,Total User Installs,Daily User Installs,Daily User Uninstalls,Active Device Installs
```

Now I have :

```
Date,Package Name,Daily Device Installs,Daily Device Uninstalls,Daily Device Upgrades,Total User Installs,Daily User Installs,Daily User Uninstalls,Active Device Installs
```

I thinks Google changed theirs output datas, but if they change that every month, that will not good for my automatic script.

If someone has informations about this changes, that can help me.
Have a good day,

Ben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/changelog) that Google periodically update the Google Analytics in order to deliver new features and to repair defects discovered in previous versions. In most cases, these changes will be transparent to API developers. Take note that, *"However, occasionally we need to make changes that require developers to modify their existing applications."*

If you think it is a bug, you create an issue in the [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). The proper person from Google team will look into your issue there, and will check if it really is a bug or not.

Answer (score 2):

Official response of Google -> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7003402#active_devices